# Java JDBC Lazy-Loaded ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, lazy-loading, resultset

Is there a way to get a ResultSet you obtain from running a JDBC query to be lazily-loaded?  I want each row to be loaded as I request it and not beforehand.

Comment: Without knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve I may be making a sweeping generalization but this sounds like quite a strange thing to do with potential performance issues if the driver implementation actually does do remote call for each row (which as pointed out in the answers below won't necessarily be the case).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Use `Statement.setFetchSize(1)` before calling `executeQuery()`.

#### Long answer:

This depends *very* much on which JDBC driver you are using.  You might want to take a look at [this page](http://webmoli.com/2009/02/01/jdbc-performance-tuning-with-optimal-fetch-size/), which describes the behavior of MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, and DB2.

Major take-aways:

- Each database (i.e. each JDBC driver) has its own default behavior.
- Some drivers will respect `setFetchSize()` without any caveats, whereas others require some "help".

MySQL is an especially strange case.  See [this article](http://benjchristensen.wordpress.com/2008/05/27/mysql-jdbc-memory-usage-on-large-resultset/).  It sounds like if you call `setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE)`, then it will download the rows one at a time, but it's not perfectly clear.

Another example: [here's the documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/query.html#query-with-cursor) for the  PostgreSQL behavior.  If auto-commit is turned on, then the ResultSet will fetch all the rows at once, but if it's off, then you can use `setFetchSize()` as expected.

One last thing to keep in mind:  these JDBC driver settings only affect what happens on the client side.  The server may still load the entire result set into memory, but you can control how the client *downloads* the results.

Comment: With the implication being that you can't rely on the one row retrieved per call to ResultSet.next() and therefore, imho, this probably isn't the solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks for your comment.  I tried to re-phrase the answer to explain that, in theory, setFetchSize() is the answer, but again, it depends on which database you're using.  This *might* be the right answer if, for example, the OP is using Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Could you not achieve this by setting the fetch size for your Statement to 1?

If you only fetch 1 row at a time each row shouldn't be loaded until you called next() on the ResultSet.

e.g.

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.setFetchSize(1);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT .....");
while (resultSet.next())
{
  // process results. each call to next() should fetch the next row
}
```

Comment: Could you please describe how to do this?

Comment: This will only work for sequential iteration, and will not allow fetching of data outside the initial statement scope. But its a good suggestion for use in trivial cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer provided [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/cy13qDea6uI).

Quote:

> The Presto JDBC driver never buffers the entire result set in memory. The server API will return at most ~1MB of data to the driver per request. The driver will not request more data from the server until that data is consumed (by calling the `next()` method on ResultSet an appropriate number of times).
>
> Because of how the server API works, the driver fetch size is ignored (per the JDBC specification, it is only a hint).

[Prove that the `setFetchSize` is ignored](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/92fbcd17acf4b6a2980187ba0b889c088952ae85/presto-jdbc/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/jdbc/PrestoResultSet.java#L714)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would want to do is defer the actually loading of the ResultSet itself.  You would need to implement that manually.

Answer (score -3):

You will find this a LOT easier using [hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/performance.html). You will basically have to roll-your-own if you are using jdbc directly.

The fetching strategies in hibernate are highly configurable, and will most likely offer performance options you weren't even aware of.

Comment: I think the down votes are because it doesn't answer the question, not because the advice is wrong per se.

Comment: And Hibernate does actually the opposite by giving you a List.