# Java: Retrieving data from Database and load in JTable

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I know how to retrieve data (just text in a table) from a database in Java and how to show it in the console. But I want to load it in a JTable.
Is there a good (modern) way (tutorial), without using Vectors?

Comment: Please research your topic before asking a question; there are many tutorials out there which can be found with a simple Google search.

Comment: duplicated at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774481/filling-object-data/8774505 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775076/jtablejdbc-easiest-way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this tutorial: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 2):

Seems your question is similar with these two questions:

[How to fill data in a JTable with database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192764/how-to-fill-data-in-a-jtable-with-database)

[Displaying data from database in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357349/displaying-data-from-database-in-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

Check out GlazedLists it comes with ready made TableModels that are based on modern collection interfaces.

http://www.glazedlists.com/

If you don't want to use an extra library.  You can easily implement your own [javax.swing.table.TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html).  I like to implement TableModel and java.util.List so I'm working with just a simple List, and hooking up any List easily.