# Filling Object[] data

Tags: java, database

I have defined a variable with

```
Object[] data;
```

How can I fill it up with data in the next step?

I want to do something like this:

```
    public Object[] select() {
   Object[] data; // Here I definded it
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS");
        while (rs.next()) {

/* data = {(rs.getString("fname"), (rs.getString("lname")); */
// I know it's wrong, but how can I fill it with data from a database?

        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("error while selecting");
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    return data;
}


// -----
// somewhere else
model.addRow(DB.INSTANCE.select());
```

Comment: A duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751735/java-retrieving-data-from-database-and-load-in-jtable — why post the same question twice?

Comment: A duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775076/jtablejdbc-easiest-way apparently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

```
 data[i++] = new Object[] {rs.getString("fname"), rs.getString("lname")};
```

But frankly I'd look at the option of creating a new class. I even have a fancy name for it: `Customer`.

So that your main cycle would look like that:

```
 while (rs.next()) {
     data[i++] = new Customer(rs.getString("fname"), s.getString("lname"));
 }
```

Now you may ask what's `i` and how do we create the `data` in the first place? All good questions. You don't know beforehand how long the result set is going to be, so arrays are not a good idea. Try using `List` instead:

```
public List<Customer> select() {
    List<Customer> data = new ArrayList<Customer>(); // Here you define it
    // some code
        while (rs.next()) {
            data.add(new Customer(rs.getString("fname"), (s.getString("lname")));
        }
    // etc.
    return data;
}
```

Note that you can almost read it aloud: `data`, add a new `Customer`, please.

Finally, I highly recommend you to take a look at the `finally` keyword: it will save you time otherwise spent on strange and intermittent bugs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Even if I just want to load the new data into a JTable? I don't want to operate with them in any way.

Comment: Maybe you can create an addRow method that directly selects and updates the JTable ?

Comment: @kavuch especially if you just want to show the data in a JTable: look at custom `TableModel`s, aren't they shiny? Seriously, it depends. If you just need a 2D array, use `new Object[] {rs.getString("fname"), rs.getString("lname")};` reading elements, a `List<Object[]>` to hold those, and `return data.toArray(new Object[data.size()][]);` to get the resulting matrix. It is an awful approach, though, and I'd never recommend it.

Comment: @Cemre what about encapsulation? You'll end up with a method that knows about both DB details and Swing internals—a nice mess indeed.

Comment: You mean, I really should create a new class, only for loading my data into a JTable? Sorry, but I think it's too much work for such a small thing. No, I'm not lazy, I just don't think, it's really necessary. There are many tutorials using Vectors, for example, but I find them ugly...

Comment: @kavuch if all you have in your application is this table, then it's not too much work: it's only one class.  If, on the other hand, you have a dozen of tables in your app, trying to find the ends will be a nightmare. Using data matrices only works if you don't care about the actual data meaning (e.g. Machine Learning: it's all "features") or if you're building a throw-away protottype. I think it's the latter case, so go on.

Comment: @kavuch now regarding `Vector`s, it's a legacy code for you. No one likes them these days, but `DefaultTableModel` is all Vectors.

Comment: @alf I see your point but I once read that objects should tell each other what they want to happen rather than querying each other for state and do the task themselves (i.e A tells B to update the table rather than query B to get the state and update the table itself). What is your opinion about this ?

Comment: @Cemre that's a call for a long article. In brief, there's no "but," there's "and also..."—you're right, but you still need to separate the concerns.

Comment: @alf: writing "data.add(new Customer(rs.getString("fname"), (rs.getString("lname")));" I receive: "array required, but java.util.List<Customer> found".

Comment: @kavuch that's hard to believe. `new Customer(rs.getString("fname"), (s.getString("lname"))` creates a `Customer`, not a `java.util.List<Customer>`. I guess your problem is in a different line.

Comment: Sorry, but that is the truth: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - array required, but java.util.List<callcenter.Customer> found
 at callcenter.DB.select(DB.java:59)`

Comment: Very interesting exception. I believe you're using NetBeans, and the problem is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this — as of the code, it seems you're mixing several approaches: what you store to the `List` must correspond the list's declared generic type. Unfortunately, comments are not a good fit for a discussion, so either create a new question outlining this very problem, or just check all the types: IDE should highlight the violations for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use an array list in this case (since your probably dont how much data that the "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS" query will return) and make use of its .add method instead of using a native array.

Try:

```
ArrayList<Object> myArray = new ArrayList<Object>(); 

while(...){
   myArray.add(anything that has type Object);
}
```