# JTable+JDBC: Easiest way

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a class `View` with a JTable and another class `DB`.
In `DB` is a method with a database connection.
When calling this method from `View`, I want it to return the whole data from the database.
What exactly should I use as the return type?
List, Vector, Array, Map,...?

I read lots of tutorials, but got very confused of the various possibilities.
I really nead the easiest way, just to understand how it works.

Comment: *"What exactly should I use as the return type?"*  The [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) would be my 1st choice.

Comment: duplicated at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774481/filling-object-data/8774505 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751735/java-retrieving-data-from-database-and-load-in-jtable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type should be whatever you want your TableModel to support.

See [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for some ideas.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what I want. I have just plain text and Integers in my database. Is there something like a "comparisson" of those types to choose the right one?

Comment: As Bill has already noted below, the simplest is the DefaultTableMdoel if you don't know what you want. Then as you become more experienced with using TableModels you can start to create custom and reusable models.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way is to put your data in vectors, and then construct a Vector from the data, and then construct a [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29) with that data.

If all you need to do is view the data this is the easiest way. Its not really a good way for viewing the data though, and its really quite bad when it comes to editing.